# How to pass datetime object as an argument into class?

Tags: python, oop, datetime, types

I am new in Python Classes. I want pass a datetime object to the `Person` class as `birth_date`.

This is what I have now:

```
import datetime

class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, birth_date):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name


    def fullname(self):
        return self.first + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want your `birth_date` to already be a `datetime object` or do you want it to be a `string` and to convert it do `datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, birth_date):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.birth_date = datetime.strptime(birth_date, '%b %d %Y')

    def fullname(self):
        return self.first + ' ' + self.last_name

person = Person('John', 'Doe', 'Jun 1 2005')

print(person.birth_date)
```

Returns:

```
2005-06-01 00:00:00
```

You assumed a particular date format, which you can modify as you see fit. Reference to docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciated.